# Removing characters and word duplicates within each column of a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
index       A 
  0      {"word1"}
  1      {"word2, word2, word2"}
  2      {"word3, word3, word3, word3, word3"}
  3      {"word36"}
     .....
 987     {"word768, word768"}
```

My objective is to remove the curly brackets and the quotation marks in each row of column A and reduce the duplicates of words to just one instance.

So, my desired result would be the following:

```
index       A 
  0       word1
  1       word2
  2       word3
  3       word36
     .....
 987      word768
```

I have been trying to solve the two objectives (replacing duplication and removing the characters) separately. To remove curly brackets and quotation characters I have tried iterating over each row and applying `str.replace`:

```
 for ind in df.index:
      df['A'].str.replace(' "{ ', " ")
      df['A'].str.replace(' }" ', " ")
```

This doesn't seem to do anything? When I `print(df)`, it gives me my original dataframe, with no change

For the duplicates, I have tried:

```
 df.drop_duplicates(['A'])
```

However, this just removes duplicates of entire rows (which is useful in its own way, just not what i'm looking for)

Next, I tried some methods found here on stack exchange:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

df['A2'] = (df['A'].str.split()
                          .apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())
                          .str.join(' '))
```

This code (just meant to remove duplicates) doesn't give me an error, but it adds a new column (A2), that is completely identical to A. I am quite new to python, so I don't understand the full workings of this latest stack example.

Any feedback on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The entries of column A are ALL type string.

EDIT 2:
After one user's suggestion, I have done the following:
df["A"].str.extract('(\w+)')

This returns a dataframe which removes the desired characters and returns the first word in the string - which does remove duplicates, however it cuts off some strings with multiple non duplicate words.

For example:

```
  index       A 
    85      {"word1, word2"}
```

becomes

```
   index       A
    85      {word1}
```

I wish to include all non duplicating words too.

Comment: What is the type of column A, string?

Comment: Yes @DaniMesejo they are all strings. I will now put this detail in.

Comment: `df["A"].str.extract('(\w+)')`?

Comment: @HenryYik Thank you, this gets me quite far!  It returns a df with all the curly brackets, quotations gone and all the duplicated words reduced to one.

Comment: However, it just gives me the first word from each entry - this eliminates those entries with multiple but not duplicate words. sorry - i should have mentioned this.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `eval()` on the column:

```
df['New'] = df['New'].apply(eval)
```

Comment: this returns the error "name 'word1' is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

read the data line by line using:

```
 for row in file.readlines():
```

now split each row to have the first words:

```
b=row.split(',')
```

Note that your splitter is "," not space (as you used in your second code)

now b[0] (or b[1] depends on the data, if index column is part of the data, then use b[1]. Check it.) is the first word. so you can append it or print it.